# eclipse not working - No java virtual machine was found

Tags: java, eclipse, netbeans, osx-snow-leopard

I installed eclipse and netbeans on mac osx 10.6
I installed android sdk and everything was working perfectly.

Now I installed mac ports
and installed ImageMagick using macports

Now after restarting the system neither netbeans work nor eclipse.

Net beans closes without any error. and eclipse give following error :

> A JDK or JRE must be installed in
>   order to run eclipse No java virtual
>   machine is found after searching the
>   following location:
>   /Users....../eclipse.app
>   ContentsMacOS/jre/bin/java java in you
>   current PATH

I thought the problem might be with the path.

So I tried running java and javac from terminal. But these two commands run properly.

note: I don't have javaw (I am not sure whether we have this file in mac or not.

Can I know what can be the problem and how can I fix it ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

@all thanks a lot.

It some or how works after two restarts don no why..

Thanks and sorry for the trouble

Answer (score 26):

In the Eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS/eclipse.ini file put

```
-vm 
/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/CurrentJDK/Home/bin/java
```

right before

```
 -vmargs
```

should help, I hope ... I hope

Comment: Your answer helped me, with a small modification. I suggest running 
`ls -l \`which java\` | cut -d">" -f2-`
and adding its result as the string following the '-vm' parameter.

Comment: This worked, thanks. But anyone knows, what was the issue?

Answer (score 3):

Check your Eclipse directory -- and look in eclipse.ini for this line:

```
-vm
<path to java.exe - e.g. C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jdk1.6.0_18/bin/javaw.exe>
```

You're probably missing that

Comment: I am running on mac so I don think I can set that -vm thingy :(

Comment: the -vm option is present for all eclipse versions -- including mac, linux etc

Comment: P.S. I gave my settings as an example on my Windows PC but it will be just a different path on Mac

Answer (score 3):

For newer versions: Mac OS X El Capitan Version 10.11.6 path to current Java version is:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/Current/Commands/java
```

For Eclipse Neon.1 open the eclipse.ini file from

```
Eclipse.app/Contents/Eclipse/eclipse.ini
```

and update the vm argument to:

```
-vm 
/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/Current/Commands/java
```

just before

```
-vmargs
```

Answer (score 3):

For me updating the eclipse.ini with -vm did not help. Rather, I had to update Eclipse.app/Contents/info.plist with below content(replace *`$Actual Java location$`* with location of java:

```
<string>-vm</string><string>*$Actual Java location$*</string>
```

Answer (score 1):

**For windows 7 - 64 bit users ( may work for others too )**
 you may do the following

**1.** If the java Runtime is NOT already installed, (Note it does not get installed along with Android SDK, you need to download it separately ). You can download from here http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html (select 'Java Platform (JDK) 7u21' out of the three option the first button :) )

after install you will find javaw.exe in " C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\bin"

**2.** set the environment variable the steps as below

a) Right click Computer, select properties, select 'advance system setting'

b) Under Advanced tab select the last button 'Environment Variable'

c) Under System settings in the window that comes next search for 'Path'

d) select 'Path' click edit

e) Add the  '**; C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\bin**'  (this path or which ever path its installed in your machine, semi colon is used to separate other pre-existing path variables, and no need of quote ;) )

Thats all !! Now try running Eclipse.exe ( **note : if you have added the entry in eclipse.ini as suggested by some ..please remove it else it will throw another exception**)

**Remember no need to change the eclipse.ini**

It works  Just double click the eclipse.exe :)

Answer (score 1):

OK. So I did add

`-vm

/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/CurrentJDK/Home/bin/java`

to eclipse.ini file but it was always overwritten when I restarted the Eclipse.

So, the thing I have done is:

1. I've created the folder structure `mkdir -p jre/Contents/Home/jre/bin/` in main eclipse folder
2. Changed dir to: `cd jre/Contents/Home/jre/bin/`
3. Made symlink to $JAVA_HOME/bin/java folder: `ln -s /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.6.0/Home/bin/java`

And after that Eclipse works every time!

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

In eclipse Go to **Windows --> Preferences --> Java --> Installed JRE's** and see whether any JRE in mentioned there.

Comment: Eclipse shows error before opening.. How DO i Set prepfrences in that case.. Plus I have prob with net beans too..

Comment: those settings are not for the JRE's used by Eclipse on startup, but for the JRE's/JDK's used by Eclipse when running Java classes from within Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

*Caveat:* I don't know anything about the Mac, so YMMV.

Check your JAVAHOME environment variable.  On most systems, that is how the JRE broadcasts its location to apps that want to run under the current JRE.

Comment: My PATH varible alrady includes java

Comment: The PATH and JAVAHOME are different.  The PATH is how the OS finds the java executable, the JAVAHOME is how the JRE knows where its files/libraries are installed.  Eclipse uses more than just the executable so it needs the JAVAHOME to point to the JRE you want it to use.

Answer (score 0):

Download the offline executable file on Java.com and make sure that if your system is 32-bit or 64-bit you should download the one that is appropriate with your system. After installing Java try running eclipse and it should run.

Answer (score 0):

Go to "environment variables" from "advance system settings".

Add JAVA_HOME variable (both user and system variables) and value= "path of jre" example: "`C:\Program Files\Java\JDK_1.8\jre\bin`".

Add jre path to "Path" variable "`...; C:\Program Files\Java\JDK_1.8\jre\bin`".

Then it works..

If still there is a problem, copy jre directory to path where Eclipse IDE Application works.

Answer (score 0):

Launching eclipse via terminal worked for me. Try that.